# Generate a 2D array with counter using list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I am new to python and learning more about list comprehensions. I want to generate a simple 2D array like this:

**Expected List:**

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4],[5, 6, 7, 8],[9, 10, 11, 12],[13, 14, 15, 16]]
```

**What I have tried:**

```
[[j for j in range(6)] for _ in range(6)]

[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Maybe i need some kind of counter instead of `j` inside the second loop, however doing `count += 1` is not allowed here and will give a syntax error.

Comment: Well firstly your output has 4s but your input uses 5s. Secondly, note that the `x`th row starts with `4x + 1`.

Comment: sorry my mistake.. I have corrected it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple solution using `range(start, stop[, step])` function with `step` argument:

```
result = [list(range(i, i+4)) for i in range(1, 16, 4)]
print(result)
```

The output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]
```

> For a positive step, the contents of a range `r` are determined by the
>   formula `r[i] = start + step*i` where `i >= 0` and `r[i] < stop`.

Answer (score 1):

```
[[a for a in range(1+(4*b), 5+(4*b))] for b in range(0, 4)]
```

this uses the same list comprehension.

**Output:**

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Nested list comprehensions :

```
[[j+i*4 for j in range(1,5)] for i in range(4)]
```

Output :

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do your derivation by creating a for loop:

```
l = []
n = 4
for i in range(3):
    l2 = [j + (n*i) for j in range(n)]
    l.append(l2)
```

Then convert that to a list comprehension:

```
x = [[j + (n*i) for j in range(n)] for i in range(3)]
```

Output:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also use [`get_chunks()`](http://utilspie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#get-chunks) function of [`utilspie`](http://utilspie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#get-chunks) library:

```
>>> from utilspie.iterutils import get_chunks

>>> list(get_chunks(range(1, 17), 4))
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]
```

*Note:* `utilspie` is not a built-in libary. You have to install it explicitly from [*pip*](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/utilspie) via doing:

```
sudo pip install utilspie
```